# How do I generate this layout?

Tags: html, css

I want to create a template like the below image.

The yellow block displays a transparent background colour over the top of the header block.

How can I do this using HTML & CSS?

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Can you transfer this question to Stackoverflow please?

Answer (score 1):

**Absolute positioning inside relative objects** in CSS will give you the ability to position an object outside of the normal flow and to overlap items.

The outer element (which holds the object) should be set to `position: relative` and the object inside it that you want to control freely should be set to `position:absolute`.

The position of the absolute object can then be controlled by the `left`, `right`, `top` and `bottom` properties.

Also, you may find `z-index` helpful as this specifies the order that objects are layered on top of each other.

Read more here: http://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/

Comment: I'd say make green relative, and give yellow `top: -[heightBlue]px; left: -[widthYellow]px;`. That way you dont have to think about all the absolute stuff and more important, you dont have to think about what will happen to the rest of your site